# .Net AzureBlobLoggerOptions - properties - documentation?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

**Environment:**

```
Windows 10
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.11.9
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.11.9+32106.194
Target framework is .NET 5.0
```

Trying to set various logging properties for an Azure Web App using the [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices) provider package.

Within Visual Studio, Intellisense shows the property "**FileNameFormat**" - and indicates the default format is "AppName/Year/Month/Day/Hour/Identifier".  However, I cannot seem to find ANY documentation with regard to this property.

The [AzureBlobLoggerOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.azureappservices.azureblobloggeroptions?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) documentation does not include the FileNameFormat property!

Should this package even be used for .Net 5/6?

Any information would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices at version 6.x supports .net6. You can for sure use AzureBlobLoggerOptions in .net6. For example it can be used along with Azure App Service -> App Service Logs -> Azure logging (blob) -> Azure Storage Account -> Blob container.

The FileNameFormat option exists in package version 6.0.9 (and probably newer versions as well). I figured out from inspection of the source that is a delegate of type Func<AzureBlobLoggerContext, string> (you probably know this means it takes an input parameter of type AzureBlobLoggerContext and returns a string). It is automatically initialized (inline), being set to a delegate that returns a string with the "AppName/Year/Month/Day/Hour/Identifier" format.

The BlobLoggerProvider (named in logging config as AzureAppServicesBlob) uses FileNameFormat to determine how it should structure the blob folder structure (which depending on amount of logging can be quite annoying when it creates a new log file every hour).  You can change the format by re-setting the FileNameFormat option like this (in my example below I've changed the format to "AppName/Year/Month/Day/Identifier")...

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices;

    builder.Services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
    {
        loggingBuilder.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();

        loggingBuilder.Services.Configure<AzureBlobLoggerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.BlobName = "MyLog.txt";
            options.IsEnabled = true;
            options.FileNameFormat = context => 
                $"{context.AppName}/{context.Timestamp:yyyy}/{context.Timestamp:MM}/{context.Timestamp:dd}/{context.Identifier}";
        });
    });
```